# Angular 2 error when declaring custom pipe on AppModule

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a custom pipe that takes a number and displays an empty screen if equal to a value passed as parameter. I created the pipe file by copy + pasting the Tour of Heroes example, and then added the pipe on the declarations array of AppModule, as the ToH mentioned. However, when I run the code, I get an error before page loads, saying

> "metadata_resolver.js:275 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value
>   'BlankIfPipe' declared by the module 'AppModule"

I am using Angular version 2.0.2. If I update to 2.1 I get all sorts of errors.

Here is my pipe (although it does not seem to be caused by it as the declarations array throws the error):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

Pipe({ name: 'blankIf' })
export class BlankIfPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number, replaceIf: number): string {
        return value === replaceIf ? '' : value.toString();
    }
}
```

the AppModule has this (some imports where removed):

```
import { LabTestService } from './lab-test/lab-test.service';
import { BlankIfPipe } from './blank-if.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        BlankIfPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        CoreModule,
        LabTestModule
    ],
    providers: [ LabTestService ], // should this be moved to LabTestModule?
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is that real code? If so you're missing the `@` before `Pipe`

Comment: @peeskillet I believe I suck at Copy + Paste :( Thanks, that was it, if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `@` before `Pipe({ name: 'blankIf' })`. Without it, it doesn't get treated like a decorator, and doesn't add the required pipe metadata to the class. So when you try to add the pipe to the `declarations`, it isn't recognized as a pipe, as it doesn't have the pipe metadata.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get this error, perhaps you can help me with this as well? zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'blankIf' could not be found

Comment: You need to declare it in the module that uses it. It won't get inherited from the app module

Comment: OK, moving the declaration to the module I used worked, but how do I make it global then? Docs said to declare it on AppModule (I actually use a SharedModule but placing it in either did not work)

Comment: There's no such thing as making `component/directives/pipes` global. It doesn't work like providers. Using a `ShareModule`, you need to both add it to the `declarations` and `exports`. And whatever module needs, add the `SharedModule` to its `imports`

Comment: Cool, I was missing the Export on SharedModule. Thanks again!